# Windows 8 user folder

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer

I used to use a separate drive for my files, so I had the freedom of creating whatever folder I wanted. However, with my new PC, I want to use Windows 8's user folder as my main folder.

1. I removed the Links folder, but now my Favorites are gone. How can I have Favorites links and not have a Links folder in my user folder?
2. I want to remove the Desktop folder, but Windows won't let me.
3. Can I hide specific files/folders? I checked "Show hidden files and folders" to view files like `.htaccess`. However, I don't want the `AppData` folder in my folder. How can I hide it or move it elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

*Links* folder **is** your favorites folder, so removing *Links* equals removing your favorites. *Desktop* folder **is** your desktop and you cannot remove your desktop.

In my opinion the problem here is your concept of "main folder". The correct approach would be to use those folders how they were designed to be used. Keep your documents in *Documents*, pictures in *Pictures* and so on.

Don't mess with profile directory's inner structure - remember that it's a system folder and it's easy to break something. Why would you need `.htaccess` in your profile folder? Just don't point Apache to serve it. Actually, don't point *any* application to it. Again, it's a system folder. Don't touch it. *Documents* are yours. *Music* is yours. Profile directory is for your OS.

If any of your files aren't either documents, pictures, music, downloads and so on, use additional partition to keep them the way you like. You don't have to choose between system-provided libraries and your folders on another drive, using both is fine. Actually, since Windows 7 you can even add your folders to libraries without moving them around.

It may sound like a mess, but in fact it can work quite well. You just have to get used to it. For example, my *Documents* folder holds mostly Office documents and some PDFs. I have few pictures in *Pictures* too. Most of the files I use daily don't match any of those, so I keep them in other proper places. Apache documents are in `C:\xampp\htdocs`. Virtual machines are in `D:\VirtualBox\`. My third partiton, `E:`, is a storage partition - I use it for storing large files that I don't use very often, of course with proper directory structure so I can navigate quickly. Strategically located shortcuts/symlinks let me jump between logically connected folders quickly.

Remember, Windows isn't as flexible as you are. Sometimes you have to trust that it knows what it's doing and let it do it's job. Messing with its folders isn't a good idea. Windows isn't an example of brilliant filesystem design, you just have to cope with that.